# Bootstrap container not centered correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm probably making a wacky error, but after looking around and looking around couldn't find it.

I'm using Rachel Baker's Bootstrap WP to build a website for a photographer, but it seems like the container div is not centered. Case in point -->

[image]

This is what my html looks like, for the header for example :

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/img/logo.png" alt="####not for google" />
                    </a>
                </div><!--logo-->
            </div><!--span.logo-->
            <div class="span5 offset1">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <?php wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'menu' => 'main-menu',
                            'container_class' => 'nav-collapse collapse',
                            'menu_class' => 'nav',
                            'fallback_cb' => '',
                            'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
                            'walker' => new Bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                        )
                    ); ?>
            </div><!--span-->

        </div>
    </div>
</header><!--header-->
```

What is it I'm missing? :S

Comment: Looks like the entire site is off-center...do you have a working example to view?

Comment: Any chance of a link to the site to view an example?

Comment: Oof, Mike, just figured it out. There was a wacky margin in a transition script from a pervious developer. Please feel free to answer and I'll give you the point

Comment: I didn't do anything...I'd just delete the question. Not really how SO works. ;)

Comment: To me it looks like you are missing space about the size of vertical sidebar on the side. Do you have sidebar on this page? Also what does your box model looks like for both container and header. check if box model has some padding or margins on it.

Comment: What exactly are you looking at @FarrukhSubhani? lol What side bar? And what model are you referring too?

Comment: I was looking at top image. I know there is no sidebar visible in image but the actual width missing in alignment was quite same size as sidebar which is about say 22px or so for most browsers. People tend you use css to offset that with the shift that happens when sidebar is visible and when its not. I was referring to padding and margins on container and header elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oof, thanks for the assistance guys!

There was stray css in a transition script, which was making this happen. Farrukh was right, I  think the previous developer was trying to account for some sort of sidebar on the left side.